# Piyyutim as replacements for prayers

Tags: song-poetry

I seem to encounter the following theory regarding *piyyutim* fairly requently:

The *piyyutim* were originally composed as **replacements** for the fixed texts of the various blessings in the prayer service.

(see e.g. the lede of [this Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%95%D7%98) article)

What are the earliest sources (both rabbinic and academic) to explicitly state this theory? And what are the main pieces of evidence that those early sources use to support this claim?

Comment: Hm. Just last week I heard in class something similar. Not that piyyutim replaced, but that they were added in between parts of the tefilah, particularly amidah. This was in Eretz Yisrael in the Geonaic period, and this was one of the criticisms that the Babylonians had regarding the Jews of E"Y.

Comment: It's not a theory but a fact that many piyyutim were composed for replacing תפילות הקבע. We have many many manuscripts that omit entirely the usual brachot and just contain the piyyutim and the חתימות. And the ones where the original bracha remains in its entirety come much later.

Comment: @magicker72 How do we know that those manuscripts are not relying on the chazzan knowing the fixed text of the bracha by heart, and therefore not bothering to write it down?

Comment: In many cases because things that are intended to be inserted from memory are given in small letters, or as the first few words plus וכו׳, or an equivalent.

Comment: @JoelK Or we see the full את צמח bracha written out, whereas none of the other brachot have their usual forms included at all.

Comment: It's worth considering that what we call "fixed texts" may not have been what they called "fixed texts". By way of analogy, if it turns out that מי כמוך אב הרחמים זוכר יצוריו לחיים ברחמים was originally meant to replace מי כמוך בעל גבורות ומי דומה לך (or זכרינו לחיים meant to replace זוכר חסדי אבות ומביא גואל), does that mean someone composed a piyyut to replace a "fixed text" or was that common line always a basic free form addition?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86117/759

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=64180&st=&pgnum=311

Comment: @DoubleAA That article has some questionable assumptions about the history of Ashkenazi nusaḥ (among other things), and makes it sound like it came about by a game of telephone.

Answer (score 1):

The [Tur](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur,_Orach_Chaim_236.1) in 236 brings that there was a time that ויראו עינינו was said instead of maariv.