# Mistake first night of Pesach vs Dec 4 on Friday night

Tags: tefilla, mistakes, geshem-tal-ruach, kitzur-shulchan-aruch

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch writes in Siman 19 Halacha 9, that if one began his Shemoneh Esrei on the first night of Pesach and he accidentally began saying a weekday amidah and he came to the Bracha of barech aleinu, that he must complete it and he is to say “vsen Bracha” because the congregation is not saying “tal umatar” - if however December 4/5 fell on a Friday night and once again he said a weekday Shemoneh Esrei, KSA again says “vsen Bracha” because the congregation is not saying “tal umatar” as of yet. 
Aren’t these 2 halachos in contradiction with each other, as if with Pesach he holds that the person changes early his recitation to "vsen Bracha," even though the congregation hasn’t changed yet, why not the same on Dec 4-5 that falls on a Friday night - why not change to vsen tal in a similar fashion?

Comment: All the more so since on December 4 it switches at Maariv, while on Pesach it switches only the next day at Mussaf Chazaras HaShatz.

Comment: I think the logic is that veten bracha is the default and veten tal umatar is an addition.

Comment: @Doniel On Pesach it also changes at maariv of motzei chag

Comment: @JoelK I mean morid hageshem changes at those points.

Comment: @DonielF Gotcha

Comment: @Joel https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82490/759

Comment: It seems everyone above is speaking about geshem and tal - not vsen bracha and vsen tal. Also, @DoubleAA - from that source it seems that vsen bracha isn't needed at all - so why in both of these situations is vsen bracha the default?

Comment: @Draizy ותן ברכה is the null case. The only required addition is ותן מטר. JoelKs claim is that null is the default (like the Tur). Tal is never required, it's just an option to augment.

Comment: @DoubleAA - isnt it vice versa - "ותן ברכה" not needed as it is not included in many versions of it and ותן טל ומטר לברכה the required one?

Comment: @Draizy ותן מטר is required. You can add טל to that or to ותן ברכה if you want but you don't have to.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Thanks so much for your time! how does that work with a standard Ashkenaz summer siddur where they only say ותן ברכה? How does all of this fly with this KSA?

Comment: I just now noticed thanks to @Joelk that KSA is cholek on Baer Heytev and halachot Ketanot

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20296&st=&pgnum=81

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the Kitzur's ruling is that the default (or 'null' - hat-tip @Double AA) state is to recite *v'ten bracha*. *V'ten tal umatar* is a mandated addition to the *amidah* during a certain season. (See [this question and its answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82488/not-saying-vsain-bracha/) for support for this assertion.)

The season starts the first weekday *arvit* on or after December 4th/5th (in the Diaspora) and extends until *minchah* of *erev pesach*.

Thus, if December 4th/5th falls on *shabbat*, the season does not begin until after *shabbat*, and one would not add *v'ten tal umatar* on that *shabbat*.

Conversely, at *arvit* of the first night of *pesach*, the season is already over, so, again, one would not recite *v'ten tal umatar*.

I think that the Kitzur's references to the recitation of the *tzibbur* is his way of ascertaining whether or not one is currently in the *v'ten tal umatar* season.

Answer (score 0):

The words of the KSA are:

> טעה במעריב ליל ראשון של פסח והתפלל תפלת שמונה עשרה של חול, ונזכר לאחר שהתחיל ''ברך עלינו'', שהדין הוא שצריך לסיים כל אותה ברכה (כמו שנתבאר לעיל סימן ע''ו), אינו אומר ''טל ומטר'', כיון שגם הציבור אינם אומרים.‏
>
> Extended paraphrase, following the explanation of the Chochmat Shelomo. If he made a mistake at the first night of Pesach and pray the prayer of Chol.
>
> And he realizes his mistake but is already reciting the Birkat Hashanim, he must go to the end of the Beracha (as explained in Siman 76, that the berachot of Yom Chol are not off topic on Shabbat, but Chachamim wanted to lighten the text in honor of Shabbat).
>
> So when he is in the middle of the blessing, he must be careful not to say "Veten Tal Umatar", because the congregation already ceased to say it for this year.
>
> ואם חלה השאלה (הוא יום התחלת לשאול טל ומטר) ביום שבת, וטעה והתפלל של חול, והתחיל "ברך עלינו" גם כן, אינו אומר "טל ומטר", כיוון שהציבור עדיין לא התחילו. והיחיד נגרר תמיד אחר הציבור.‏
>
> If the same problem occurs on Shabbat at the date of switching to say "Veten Tal Umatar" if it had been possible,
>
> he have not say Tal Umatar because the congregation did still not start to say it.
>
> The logical trick is that stop mentioning this word comes automatically, but start saying these words is a congregational act.

Comment: "The stoping of veten tal umatar automatically happened on Yom Tov" Why? And how do you know that? I wouldn't expect that to be true.

Comment: I disagree. Both requests are announced.

Comment: No it's announced in Shul on Shmini Atzeret in Tefillah. Who said an announcement must be immediately adjacent to the effect? And also who said beating the Bima is a Halakhically insignificant announcement? Many places just announce Mashiv Haruach before Musaf and expect that to work even though that's not part of tefillah

Comment: @kouty I don't understand your answer. Why if a weekday Amidah was said on Leyl YT of Pesach we say that the season changed, even though the congregation hasnt change, and now it "vsen bracha" time but on December 4/5th - it hasn't changed yet BECAUSE the congregation hasn't changed and is still "vsen bracha" time - shouldnt they be the same?

Comment: Because  the veten beracha officially  changed from the evening. If it's Shabbat, this needs to be said but the official Amida skipped it.   Our man entered himself in the chyuv. As it's a standard week's day. So he needs to add it, to say veten Tal umatar correctly. If it's yom Tov of Pesach, veten tal umatar has stopped officially. But there isn't still nafka mina. He entered himself in chyuv to say birkat Hashanim. To miss veten beracha is not a missing because the hazkara stopped. If he does say it, no problem, there are poskim against the halachot Ketanot. .

Comment: @kouty "Because the veten beracha officially changed from the evening. If it's Shabbat, this needs to be said but the official Amida skipped it. Our man entered himself in the chyuv. As it's a standard week's day. So he needs to add it, to say veten Tal umatar correctly." - I am assuming you are referring to the evening of Dec 4/5. If it were a weekday he would say Vsen Bracha, NOT Vsen Tal umatar levracha" - so why if it is shabbos, does that change and the KSA hold that our guy says Vsen Bracha?

Comment: @JoelK fixed, thank you very much

Comment: @Draizy-LeviPine I did completely changed the answer. I was wrong, confusing two dinim

Comment: @kouty - once again - on Pesach, the individual does say Vsen Bracha - even though the congregation is NOT saying it as of yet due to YT, but on Dec 4th, he continues to say Vsen Bracha because the congregation hasn't stopped saying it yet - I still dont get why they should be different? On Pesach, we say it changed already, even before the tzibur, but on Dec 4, we say it hasnt changed because the tzibur hasnt changed - why?

Comment: It's not due to yom Tov, on Pesach, they simply finished their "tickets" @Draizy-Levi Pine

Comment: @kouty - can you please elaborate .. a lot. Thanks!

Comment: They have a certain amount of veten tal umatar to say this year. The quantity is finished

Comment: @kouty - so what does it mean that it is all contingent on the tzibur?

Comment: When the tdibbur started, they received the order to say veten tal umatar up to the day before pesach.  The day they received this order is the first day they started. If the night 4-5 December is Shabbat, they received the starting order at the 5-6 night

Comment: In summary there is starting order only and this order includes an "up to" order